# React native app crash when app more layers of view components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

> when ever I add this line of code in my react native app it
> crashes.The expo app closes with out no error being thrown to the
> console and its quite hard to debug because I don't see anything wrong
> with the code.
> What am thinking is it is wrong to have many views inside of a view component but I have not seen anyone complain about such error

```
<View>
  <View style={styles.sameRowContainer}>
     <View style={[styles.iconContainer, { backgroundColor: "#0CCE6B" }]}>
       <Feather name="repeat" size={14} color="white" />
     </View>
     <Text style={styles.title}>Goal</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
     <Text style={styles.title}>hello</Text>
  </View>

 </View>
```

this is the code that is render for the screen

```
return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={styles.container}
        // contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}
      >
        <View style={styles.habitNameContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Habit Name</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={onChangeTitle}
            value={title}
            placeholder={"Learn photography..."}
            placeholderTextColor={"hsla(224, 100%, 10%, 0.343)"}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.timeOfDay}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Select time of day to complete habit</Text>

          <TimeOfDay
            currentView={currentView}
            setCurrentView={setCurrentView}
          />
        </View>

        <View>
          <View style={styles.sameRowContainer}>
            <View
              style={[styles.iconContainer, { backgroundColor: "#0CCE6B" }]}
            >
              <Feather name="repeat" size={14} color="white" />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Goal</Text>
          </View>
          
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>hello</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        
        <View style={styles.dummyView}></View>
      </ScrollView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
```

this is the style for the component as well

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",

    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },

  dummyView: {
    height: 50,
  },
  habitNameContainer: {
    // width: "90%",
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  title: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 5,
    color: "hsl(0, 0%, 50%)",
  },
  input: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: "hsl(224, 100%, 98%)",
    fontWeight: "500",
  },
  timeOfDay: {
    // flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  sameRowContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "baseline",
  },

  iconContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",

    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 26,
    width: 26,
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#0CCE6B",
  },
});
```

Comment: Nested Views are fine.

Comment: How did you go about obtaining the vector icons from Feather?

Comment: import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

Comment: You may need to preload the assets: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/

Comment: Another possible issue is that you have added @expo/vector-icons in your package.json . If so, remove it.

Comment: // contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}: Not sure if that "//" is a typo in your answer but it will definitely cause problems for you if it isn't.

Comment: that is a comment but I have removed it. error still persist

Comment: What of you change style={[styles.iconContainer, { backgroundColor: "#0CCE6B" }]} to style={{…styles.iconContainer, backgroundColor: "#0CCE6B"}